# Format Error for Input into Keras using 4-channel DNA data

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, reshape

I have DNA data that I am trying to input into Keras, and I have one-hot encoded it such that each DNA sequence is 4 channels (one for each type of nucleotide). I followed some of the tutorials, but I seem to be having a formatting issue. Perhaps someone could help me out? This is the first time I've tried inputting my own data into Keras. My data looks like this:

`print(x_train.shape)
(1509, 4, 476)
print(y_train.shape)
(1509,)`

And my model (so far) looks like this:

```
###Setup Keras to create a convolutional recurrent NN
# set parameters:
batch_size = 32
filters = (32, 1, 2) #(number of filters, rows per convolution kernel, columns per convolution kernel)
kernel_size = 16
x_shape = (1509, 1, 476, 4) #(samples, height, width, depth)
epochs = 3

#declare model
model = Sequential()

#CNN Input layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters,
                 kernel_size,
                 padding='same',
                 activation='relu',
                 strides=(1,0),
                 input_shape=x_shape))
print(model.output_shape)
```

but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_0: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5
```

I am unclear on why the model is finding 5 dimensions for the `input_shape` argument when I specify 4 dimensions. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't include the number of samples in the input_shape argument. This is what the error means.
The batch size dimension is added automaticaly.

Also, you should reshape your x_train table to match the input_shape :

```
x_train = np.reshape(np.transpose(x_train, (0, 2, 1)), (x_train.shape[0], 1, x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]))
```

That way I first transposed the array into (1509, 476, 4) then added a dimension : (1509, 1, 476, 4)

I hope this helps